# Jenkins Could not find a part of the path

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is placed on remote machine. When I run tests via Jenkins I get error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path
```

But if I run tests on local machine It works ok.

Do you know why it might happened ?

Comment: Is it a relative or absolute path?

Comment: it's absolute path

Comment: Hi, can you provide details on what tests you are running and how ? Using a pipeline job in Jenkins ?